# Unable to publish workflow in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, designer-workflow

I have a workflow with a customized Approval form.

I had to make a minor change in an email sent from the workflow.

When I try to publish the workflow, I get the below error:

`The form Approval.xsn has been customized using InfoPath and may no longer be compatible with this workflow due to field changes. To continue using the existing form, you must first update it using InfoPath`

We are not aware of any changes made to the Approval form.

I currently do not have Infopath on the machine I am making the modification from.

How can I get the workflow published?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the form, then publish the workflow.

Reference：

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d959514f-75db-4aea-baa9-7f8865a02eaa/the-form-approval-xsn-has-been-customized-using-infopath-and-may-no-longer-be-compatible-with-this?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

https://sharepointcreations.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/workflow-form-update-required/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps :

- Save the workflow
- Delete the initiation form
- Then publish the workflow

The above steps, will fix the issue.

Same is discussed here :

[Workflow Form Update Required](https://www.google.com/amp/s/sharepointcreations.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/workflow-form-update-required/amp/)